# SpyOn returns Expected a spy, but got Function

Tags: unit-testing, service, controller, karma-runner, spyon

I am testing a controller that calls a service(through the goToPage function) in order to redirect using the spyOn. It's simple but I am getting "Expected a spy, but got Function." error. What am I doing wrong?
This is my Spec:

```
var createController,service scope;
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller,$injector){
    service = $injector.get('service ');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    createController = function() {
        return $controller('controller', {
            '$scope': scope
        });
        spyOn(service , ['redirect']).andCallThrough();
    };
}));

describe('test if service is called', function() {
    it('should call the service', function() {
        var controller=createController();
        scope.goToPage();
        expect(service.redirect).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you defined your spy after you called return, so that code will never be run. Second, define your spy in your test, not in beforeEach.

```
var createController,service scope;
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller,$injector){
    service = $injector.get('service ');
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    createController = function() {
        return $controller('controller', {
            '$scope': scope
        });    
    };
}));

describe('test if service is called', function() {
    it('should call the service', function() {
        var controller=createController();
        spyOn(service , ['redirect']).andCallThrough();
        scope.goToPage();
        expect(service.redirect).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: this explains the correct usage of `tohavebeencalled` method of a service from within a `controller`.. Bravo!